# FullGraphics ticks problem

Tags: plotting, ticks

In the document of FullGraphics, it promise to produce the same graphic result as the input one:

```
"FullGraphics[g] should display the same as g, though it may have a different internal structure."
```

but it has problem in the ticks and axes as the follow example, as they are too thin and the ticks position aren't the same as the original one.

```
g = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}]
Show[FullGraphics[g], AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

I have two question:

1. What is the mechanism of axes, tick etc, why they are treated different from the graphics primitives in MMA? Could you explain how MMA convert the axes, ticks etc into the graphics primitives?
2. Is there any "easy" solution to make FullGraphics to reproduce the same result as the input image, or even write one's own version of FullGraphics? Thanks. Sorry I'm a novice and I can't post the figure.

Comment: Unfortunately `FullGraphics` has many problems.  Also it doesn't work that well with all the new (post version 6) graphics functionality.  I don't think there's an *easy* solution (if there is, I'd like to know).

Comment: @Nasser Thanks for asking. I was trying to produce a 3d plot, which contains several 2d plots oriented differently in the 3d space. The first way to achieve this is to draw Polygons and put 2d plots as textures on them, but this requires rasterize the 2d plot which will produce a less nicer 3d plot than the second way. The second way is to convert the 2d plot directly into 3d by convert the 2d coordinate to 3d. This will work but on the plot content, but not on the axes or ticks in the plot, since they are not graphics primitives. FullGraphics can convert the axes, ticks etc into primitives.

Comment: I think `FullGraphics` uses the actual coordinates for aspect-ratio, so you may need to stretch the origin graphics before feeding it to `FullGraphics`. And it seems to generate ticks with `PlotRangePadding->0`, which will affect the automatic ticks generation if `PlotRange` is set to `Automatic`. About the length of ticks, it looks for me like the default style in old MMA versions (like v4), so my personal guess is, maybe it was forgotten to be adjusted to new default style?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, I'd say thank you very much to bring such an interesting function to me! I played around with it awhile and came up with the following thought, which I hope would be helpful for you.

About your first question, I'm sorry I know nothing concrete but only some guessing.

## 1. Aspect Ratio

I think `FullGraphics` uses the actual coordinates to calculate aspect-ratio (like setting `AspectRatio->Automatic` in `Plot`), so you may need to stretch the origin graphics `g` before feeding it to `FullGraphics`.

```
g = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Setting `AspectRatio` doesn't really affect the result:

```
FullGraphics /@ {g, Show[g, AspectRatio -> RandomReal[]]} // Column
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

## 2. Position of Ticks

And it seems, if `Ticks` was set to `Automatic` in the input `g`, `FullGraphics` generates ticks positions with flavor that `Plot` does with `PlotRangePadding->0`, which will affect the automatic ticks generation if `PlotRange` is set to `Automatic`(*i.e.* the default setting).

the `PlotRange` of `g`:

```
{xrange, yrange} = PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[g, PlotRange]
```

Compare two kinds of settings, where the right side column merged the original `PlotRangePadding` space into `PlotRange`:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

## 3. Length of Tick-marks

About the lengths of tick marks, it looks for me like the default style in old *Mathematica* versions (like 4.x), so my personal guess would be, maybe it was just forgotten to be adjusted to new default style.

## About your second question

So here is my homemade brute-force method:

```
Clear[labelFmtFunc]
labelFmtFunc[label_] := 
 If[label === "", "", 
  If[FractionalPart[label] == 0, Round[label], label]]

Clear[ticksStretchFunc]
ticksStretchFunc[ticksetting_, xrange_, yrange_, stretchRatio_, 
  factor_: 2] := Module[{xTicksetting, yTicksetting},
  xTicksetting = 
   ticksetting[[
     1]] /. {pos_, label_, {plen_, nlen_}, style_} :> {pos, 
      labelFmtFunc[label], factor {plen, nlen}, style};
  yTicksetting = 
   ticksetting[[
     2]] /. {pos_, label_, {plen_, nlen_}, 
      style_} :> {stretchRatio pos, labelFmtFunc[label], 
      factor {plen, nlen}, style};
  {xTicksetting, yTicksetting}
  ]

Clear[myFullGraphics]
myFullGraphics[g_Graphics, tickLengthFactor_: 2] := 
 Module[{xrange, yrange, stretchRatio, padding, newxrange, newyrange, 
   newg, ticksetting},
  {xrange, yrange} = PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[g, PlotRange];
  stretchRatio = 
   AspectRatio {-1, 1}.xrange/{-1, 1}.yrange /. 
    AbsoluteOptions[g, AspectRatio];
  padding = PlotRangePadding /. AbsoluteOptions[g, PlotRangePadding];
  {newxrange, newyrange} = 
   MapThread[#1 + {-1, 1} If[
        Head[#2] === Scaled, #2[[1]] {-1, 1}.#1, #2] &, {{xrange, 
      yrange}, padding}];
  newg = Show[g, PlotRange -> {newxrange, newyrange}];
  ticksetting = Ticks /. AbsoluteOptions[newg, Ticks];
  Show[If[Head[newg[[1]]] === GraphicsComplex,
     newg /. 
      GraphicsComplex[pts_, others__] :> 
       GraphicsComplex[
        pts /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :> {x, stretchRatio y}, 
        others],
     newg /. 
      Line[pts__] :> 
       Line[pts /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :> {x, stretchRatio y}]],
    Ticks -> 
     ticksStretchFunc[ticksetting, xrange, yrange, stretchRatio, 
      tickLengthFactor], 
    PlotRange -> {newxrange, stretchRatio newyrange}, 
    PlotRangePadding -> 0] // FullGraphics
  ]
```

Apply it on `g`:

```
myFullGraphics[g]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So it's fairly consistent with the original `g` obtained by `Plot`.

## Applications

`myFullGraphics` can be used to convert lots (though not all and not always perfectly) of 2D graphics, including those from `ContourPlot`, into *full graphics*. The following demonstrates a simple application.

Here is a `Graphics` object obtained by `myFullGraphics`:

```
fullg = PolarPlot[Sin[2 \[Theta] + 2 10^15], {\[Theta], 0, 8 Pi}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision, 
   PlotRange -> {{-1.1, 1.1}, {-1.1, 1.1}}, 
   PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled[.02], Scaled[.02]}] // 
  myFullGraphics[#, 30] &
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We map it onto the surfaces of several ellipsoids (note the `axesRules`, I manually converted the axes lines which contains only two endpoints into a line with more points):

```
Map[With[{range = PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[fullg, PlotRange], 
     uShift = 0, vShift = 0, rShift = #},
    Clear[transFunc];
    transFunc[{x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ}] := Module[{u, v},
      u = Rescale[x, range[[1]], \[Pi]/9 {-1, 1} + uShift];
      v = Rescale[y, range[[2]], \[Pi]/2 + \[Pi]/9 {-1, 1} + vShift];
      rShift {Sin[u] Sin[v], 1.4 Cos[u] Sin[v], Cos[v]}
      ];
    Module[{graphComplexTemp, axesRules},
     axesRules = {SortBy[
          Cases[fullg, Line[{{_, y_}, {_, y_}}], \[Infinity]], 
          Abs[{-1, 1}.#[[1, All, 1]]] &][[-1]] /.
        Line[{{x1_, y_}, {x2_, y_}}] :> (Line[{{x1, y}, {x2, y}}] -> 
           Line[{#, y} & /@ Range[x1, x2, (x2 - x1)/100]]),
       SortBy[Cases[fullg, Line[{{x_, _}, {x_, _}}], \[Infinity]], 
          Abs[{-1, 1}.#[[1, All, 2]]] &][[-1]] /.
        Line[{{x_, y1_}, {x_, y2_}}] :> (Line[{{x, y1}, {x, y2}}] -> 
           Line[{x, #} & /@ Range[y1, y2, (y2 - y1)/100]])};
     Graphics3D @@ fullg /.
           GraphicsComplex[pts_, 
             others__] :> (graphComplexTemp = 
              GraphicsComplex[transFunc /@ pts, others]; 
             "graphComplexTemp") /.
          axesRules /.
         {Point[pts__] :> 
           Point[pts /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :> 
              transFunc[{x, y}]],
          Line[pts__] :> 
           Line[pts /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :> 
              transFunc[{x, y}]],
          Arrow[pts__] :> 
           Arrow[pts /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :> 
              transFunc[{x, y}]], 
          Polygon[pts__] :> 
           Polygon[
            pts /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :> transFunc[{x, y}]],
          Text[txt_, pos_, offset_] :> 
           Text[txt, transFunc[pos], offset]} /.
        "graphComplexTemp" -> graphComplexTemp /.
       Hue[__] :> ColorData["Rainbow"][RandomReal[]] /.
      (PlotRange -> _) :> (PlotRange -> All)]
    ] &, Range[1, 2, .3]] // 
 Show[#, Axes -> True,(*AxesOrigin->{0,5,0},*)AxesStyle -> Red, 
   BoxStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[.8]], ViewPoint -> {2.5, 1.4, 1.5},
    ViewRange -> All, ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1}, 
   SphericalRegion -> True, RotationAction -> "Clip", 
   ImageSize -> 950] &
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it is exactly what I'm trying to do, especially the application part. I'm going through your code right now and I'm sure I can learn a lot from them. Thanks again.

Comment: @xslittlegrass You are welcome. The code in the application part is very rough, you may need to complete it for more general purpose.