# Diagonal Tick Marks

Tags: plotting, graphics, ticks

I would like to draw diagonal tick marks around a plot, and simultaneously rotate the tick labels as well. I've mocked up what this would look like:

[image]

Is there an easy way to do this in Mathematica? I believe this is beyond the capabilities of the CustomTicks package.

**Edit:** I would like this to be general enough to work for arbitrary plot ranges, and perhaps it would be easiest to generate the plot first with the normal tick marks, and then apply a replacement to the final graphics object?

Comment: Can you just define a graphics object, something like: `tick[startx_,starty_,n_] :=Graphics[Text[Style[ToString[n] <> ".0", 30], {startx - 0.8, starty - 0.8}, Automatic, {1, 1}]],Graphics[Line[{{startx,starty}, {startx - 0.5, starty - 0.5}}]]` and add it onto a plot with all `Ticks` removed?

Comment: Related / a possible starting point: [How to align rotated tick labels?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9530/131)

Comment: I believe it's possible to use fixed `FullGraphics` function from [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19814/fullgraphics-ticks-problem), and rotate the ticks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This was a bit harder -- and turned out more complicated -- than I thought it would be at first, mainly because at first I didn't think ahead to what would be required: To do the ticks and rotate them, you need to know the full plot range, including the padding, and the aspect ratio.  Moreover, `AbsoluteOptions` does not work the way that would make it easy to figure these things out (unless I'm missing something).

In any case, this seems to work.  The shared variables are localized in a `Module` containing the definitions.

```
Module[{
   plotrange0,          (* PlotRange *)
   plotrangepadding0,   (* PlotRangePadding *)
   aspectratio,         (* aspect ratio as a pair {x, y} *)
   xticks, yticks,      (* ranges for ticks (full plotrange) *)
   dplotrange,          (* width, height of full plotrange *)
   ticks,
   ticklen = 0.025,     (* length of ticks (const parameter) *)
   textoffset = 0.005}, (* how far from ticks to end of label (const parameter) *)

   (* convert PlotRangePadding setting to coordinate offsets *)
 paddingcvt[range_, {padX_, padY_}] := {{-1, 1} padX /. 
    Scaled[s_] :> s (range[[1, 2]] - range[[1, 1]]), {-1, 1} padY /. 
    Scaled[s_] :> s (range[[2, 2]] - range[[2, 1]])};
 paddingcvt[range_, padding_] := {{-1, 1} padding /. 
    Scaled[s_] :> s (range[[1, 2]] - range[[1, 1]]), {-1, 1} padding /. 
    Scaled[s_] :> s (range[[2, 2]] - range[[2, 1]])};
   (* calculate the plot range plus padding *)
 fullplotrange[] := plotrange0 + paddingcvt[plotrange0, plotrangepadding0];
   (* returns rotated ticks along side : tickposfn = {#, y0} or {x0, #} *)
 tickGraphics[tickrange_, Function[tickposfn_]] := GeometricTransformation[
     {Text[N@#, Scaled[{-ticklen - textoffset, 0}, tickposfn], {1, 0}], 
      Line[{Scaled[{-ticklen, 0}, tickposfn], tickposfn}]},
     rotate[\[Pi]/4, tickposfn]] & /@ 
   Select[FindDivisions[tickrange, 5], tickrange[[1]] < # < tickrange[[2]] &];
   (* returns transformation to rotate graphics, adjusting for aspect ratio distortion *)
 rotate[\[Theta]_, {a_, b_}] := Composition[
     ScalingTransform[dplotrange/aspectratio, #],
     RotationTransform[\[Theta], #],
     ScalingTransform[aspectratio/dplotrange, #]] &[{a, b}];

 slantTicks[g_] := ( (* calculate parameters *)
   plotrange0 = PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[g, PlotRange];
   plotrangepadding0 = If[# === Automatic, 
       AspectRatio /. AbsoluteOptions[g, PlotRangePadding], #] &[
     PlotRangePadding /. Options[g, PlotRangePadding]];
   {xticks, yticks} = fullplotrange[];
   dplotrange = -Subtract @@@ {xticks, yticks};
   aspectratio = If[# === Automatic, dplotrange, {1, #}] &[
     AspectRatio /. Options[g, AspectRatio]];
     (* the graphics *)
   ticks = Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[0.5], 
      Line@Tuples[{xticks, yticks}][[{1, 3, 4, 2, 1}]], 
      tickGraphics[xticks, {#, yticks[[1]]} &],
      tickGraphics[yticks, {xticks[[1]], #} &]}, PlotRange -> All];
   Show[g, ticks, Axes -> False, Frame -> None, PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
    ImagePadding -> {{20, 5}, {20, 5}}])
 ]
```

It works with `Plot`:

```
slantTicks[Plot[Sin[Pi x] + Cos[Pi x]^2, {x, 0, 10}]]
```

[image: Plot output]

It works with `Graphics`:

```
slantTicks[Graphics[{Red, Thick, Line[{{-0.5, 1.5}, {2.5, 0.55}}]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 3}, {0, 2}}, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.05]]]
```

[image: Graphics output]

It's not perfect.  Note `PlotRangeClipping` is set to `False` since `ticks` are plotted outside the `PlotRange` of `g`.
There seem to be issues whatever order of `ticks` and `g` is used in `Show`, since the options of the first override the second.

I did try to use `Ticks`, with which one can rotate the labels with dealing with the aspect ratio.  I failed, however, to figure out how to get rotated tick marks in the right places.

Comment: This is great, and exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

It's easy enough, if you like fiddling with values:

```
p = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}];
r = Graphics[{
     FaceForm[None],
     EdgeForm[{Black}],
     Rectangle[{0, -1}, {10, 1}],
     Table[
      {
       Line[{{x - .2, -1.1}, {x, -1}}],
       Text[Style[x, 12], {x - .2, -1.2}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}]
      }, {x, 0, 10}],
     Table[
      {
       Line[{{-.25, y - .1}, {0, y}}],
       Text[Style[y, 12], {-0.5, y - .2}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}]
      }, {y, -1, 1, .5}] 
     }, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio];
Show[r, p]
```

[image: plot]

If you were going to do a lot of these, it would be worth 'parameterizing' it, to save you fiddling with offsets and values. The problem of the two ticks at {0,0} is interesting, too.

Comment: That's a twisted use for the word "interesting"

Comment: @belisarius I'm hiding behind its ambiguities... :)

Comment: Just to add here, I am interested in "parameterizing" it. I will be generating hundreds of plots in this style.