# Manipulate Controller - Simplex

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction, simplex

Imagine you have three numbers `a`, `b` and `c`, and using `Manipulate` you wish to combine them in the following way: `x a + x2 b + (1-x-x2) c`.

Here,  `x`, `x2` and `x3 = 1-x-x2` must all be between `0` and `1`.This means `x`, `x2` and `x3` form a two-dimensional simplex within a three-dimensional space.

Does anyone have a nice idea of how to create a simplex (triangular) controller which allows me to move `x` and `x2`, such that `x3` is always between `0` and `1`.

I hope this is clear, at least to the people who know what a simplex is. The solution might be a `Slider2D` with some constraint.

Thanks!

Comment: Somehow related: [how to plot ternary density plots](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39733/5478)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `Manipulate`, you can demonstrate the relationship of the three simplex coordinates. Since `x` and `x2` define the value of `x3`, I added `Enabled -> False` to its controller. Another way would be to set up some rules about which variable to decrease if any of the three variables is increased (i.e. decrease `x3` if `x` or `x2` is increased, decrease `x` if `x3` or `x2` is increased, etc.) but it seems a bit unnecessary.

```
Manipulate[
 {{x, x2, x3}, Total@{x, x2, x3}} // Column,
 {{x, .5}, 0, 1 - x2, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{x2, .3}, 0, 1 - x, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{x3, .2}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled", Enabled -> False},
 Initialization :> {x3 := (1 - x - x2)}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

With another `Manipulate`, you can visualize the behaviour of your function (`f` here) depending on the values of `a`, `b` and `c`:

```
Manipulate[
 Dynamic@DensityPlot[f@trans@{x, y}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
   ColorFunction -> (Hue[0.85 #] &), BoundaryStyle -> Black,
   RegionFunction -> (inQ@transform@{#1, #2} &)],
 {{a, 1., "a"}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{b, .5, "b"}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{c, .3, "c"}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 Initialization :> {
   x3 := (1 - x1 - x2),
   f[{x_, x2_, x3_}] := x a + x2 b + (1 - x - x2) c;
   inQ[pt_List] := (Total@pt == 1 && And @@ NonNegative@pt);
   trans[{x_, y_}] := {1, 0, 0} + x*{-1, 1, 0} + 
       y*{-1/Sqrt@3, -1/Sqrt@3, 2/Sqrt@3};
   }
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks! That's the simplest method, I suppose. I like the disabled 3rd controller.

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you are after?

```
DynamicModule[{x = 0, x2 = 0},
 Framed[
  Column[{
    Dynamic[{"a", "b", "c"}.{x, x2, 1 - x - x2}],
    LabeledSlider[Dynamic[x, (x = #; x2 = Min[x2, 1 - x];) &], {0, 1}],
    Dynamic@LabeledSlider[Dynamic[x2], {0, 1 - x}]
    }]
  , Alignment -> Center, ImageSize -> {400, 100}]]
```

[image]

Or maybe, other way when `x` and `x2` does not affect values of each other but only the limits:

```
DynamicModule[{x = 0, x2 = 0},
 Framed[
  Column[{
    Dynamic[{"a", "b", "c"}.{x, x2, 1 - x - x2}],
    Dynamic@LabeledSlider[Dynamic[x], {0, 1 - x2}],
    Dynamic@LabeledSlider[Dynamic[x2], {0, 1 - x}]
    }]
  , Alignment -> Center, ImageSize -> {400, 100}]]
```

Comment: Thanks! That's great, especially the second version :)