# Adding code comments to a module

Tags: front-end, comment

What is the best way to comment a **long** Module?

For linear flowing calculations that need not be organised in modules, I usually mix text and math. But how can I do that inside a module, or block, or any other scoping construct?

Comment: `(* like this *)`.

Comment: Don't let your modules get that long.  Split them into subfunctions and comment/document those.

Comment: Probably suggestions of @"Guess who it is" and @Mr.Wizard is the only valid way in spirit of functional programming. However, it is so hard... Subfunctions are getting too specialized.

Comment: Even if a subfunction is only used *once* I do not think it hinders readability.  If the goal is clear documentation I think this is acceptable.  But it is difficult to discuss matters of style without some example.  Perhaps an existing post on this site could serve that purpose?

Comment: By the way I use `(* inline comments *)` a fair bit and I am not sure I understand your complaint about "convenience and look."  For an sample of my style, though it changes from time to time, please see: [Optimal Code Layout in Mathematica?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6322526/618728)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I was trying to find an existing post on this site for illustration. Perhaps one answer of Guess who it is can be used as an example http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39733/how-to-plot-ternary-density-plots  If text could be added here and there the module would be much more legible.

Comment: @yarchik, ah, a work in progress… so many ideas, so little computer time. :) I really should update that with new ideas when I get the chance…

Answer (score 2):

Not sure it's good practice, but in a notebook you can format the text inside the `(* *)` comment designators to your liking. Here's an example module with "Text" style used with inline comments:

[image]

Additionally, it's possible to disable evaluation for individual cells (from the menu: "Cell"-->"Cell Properties"-->"Evaluatable"), and one can use `Inactive` to prevent evaluation of whole blocks or modules.

Also, as @Mr.Wizard mentioned in his comment, it is often better practice to refactor your modules into more manageable pieces--subfunctions that work together. These smaller pieces are easier to document with explanatory text and divisions in the notebook interface, and short inline comments.