# Ternary diagram

Tags: plotting, regions, conditional

I'd like to make a RegionPlot on a ternary diagram, meaning in a triangle where the axis are $x,y,z$, which are related by $x+y+z=1$. The RegionPlot would have as a condition $x^2+y^2<1$ for example.

These are examples of ternary diagram : https://www.google.com/search?q=ternary+diagram&safe=active&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiv37DH_-7bAhWBGhQKHTPjCYMQ_AUICigB&biw=1920&bih=1089

Comment: What exactly is your question? What have you tried? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: You could take inspiration from [(39733)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39733/27951) and [(119328)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119328/27951).

Comment: Here is also a way to get more or less nice axes : [(172421)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/172421/38178).