# 3D Ternary Plot - Triangular Prism?

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

I'm new to Mathematica and I am using it as a free trial online.

I am doing a biology experiment, varying the composition of people's diet and seeing the effect of that on sleep. Because I am varying macronutrient break down, I have a three part system. (eg. 50% protein, 30% carbohydrates, 20% fat etc). I can denote this percentage diet break down on a [ternary plot](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ac/Blank_ternary_plot.svg).

I then want to extend this into 3D space because my dependent variable is sleep duration etc - how can I plot this 'y' value for a corresponding point on the ternary plot?

eg. 7 hours sleep corresponds to 50:30:20, 8 hours sleep corresponds to 40:20:40 etc

Appreciate I may not have been the clearest, so happy to explain things again if needs-be! In an attempt to make some thing clearer, I am attaching a hand drawn picture of what I think I want!

[image]

There are a couple of different ways I can visualise it in my head:

In the first idea - I have a density plot, with, for example, three different qualities of sleep.

In the second idea, the whole ternary plot becomes sort of an x axis? I then extend into the 3D plane with my sleep variable...this would be like a normal 'y' axis, i.e. the higher you go, the higher the number. Would it be possible to do this with just one sleep variable or would it have to be done with a minimum of two sleep variables? If it needs more than one sleep variable that is fine too, because I have for example, time it takes to get to sleep and deep sleep percentage too, which I could put on the same graph.

Hopefully my 'triangular prism' reference is starting to make sense now!!

Comment: Possibly related [39733](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39733/how-to-plot-ternary-density-plots)?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Mathematica.SE. Then, do you mean something like this?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/195633/1871

Comment: Hi @TimLaska - many thanks it is like that - only, I wanted to work out a way how to plot a graph like that in 3D (because of my fourth variable sleep duration). I don't know how to do that on Mathematica online. can you help with this? For example, to start with, I am unable to make a table of data with my four variables...

Comment: xzczd - thanks - I did look at that thread but it wasn't useful for what I wanted

Comment: @xzczd I am new to Mathematica online so am unable to navigate myself around the program

Comment: @TimLaska - on reflection, your density plots may be useful! If I could somehow colour code different levels of sleep then I could plot that graph.My biggest problem however still remains the fact that I am unable to decipher what on earth is going on in that thread - could you perhaps get me started with some pointers related to my specific example please? many thanks!!

Comment: 1. What exactly do you need? The question is still unclear, at least for me. 2. "I am unable to decipher what on earth is going on in that thread", which part are you haviing difficulty? Have you read this?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/1871

Comment: Thanks @xzczd - apologies for not being clear. The page you referred to had a specific example for a trig function, I was wondering if someone could get me started by giving me instructions on to proceed in my specific case. Either, I make a colour coded plot or I make a 3D density plot - in either case, what would be the first steps I need to do when I go to new workbook on Mathematica online? For example, I am even having difficultly important data onto Mathematica online. Once I have that initial guidance/leg up I might be able to get going, but right now am a bit overwhelmed! Thanks again.

Comment: The most helpful thing would be if you could find an example image of exactly (or very close to) what you're looking for (even hand-drawn can help), though such a thing may not exist. Another helpful thing might be if you could give a sample dataset for us to try plotting. I realize you may not want to post your research data, but can you randomly generate a dataset similar in size and format to the one you want to plot? One thing I'm not clear on is how the data should be represented. Should each data point be a single dot, or should there be lines or surfaces interpolating between the data?

Comment: You might also want to take a look [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DataVisualization.html) to see what kinds of visualizations are common. In particular, I would guess you want something like `ListPointPlot3D`, `ListPlot3D`, or `ListDensityPlot3D`, except with a ternary base rather than just the 2 axes. Are any of those kind of similar to what you were thinking?

Comment: @MassDefect - thank you so much - ListPlot3D and ListDensityPlot are similar to what I was thinking - I will try adding a picture to the question in the next few minutes! In terms of sample data: Carbohydrate, Protein, Fat, Sleep Duration, Sleep Quality Score       50%, 30%, 20%, 7 hours, 76% or 20% 40% 40% 8 hour 73%

Comment: @MassDefect - in general - you can make up any data set - all we have to make sure is that the percentages of the three components add up to 100%. Then you can give a random number to the sleep duration and a random percentage to the sleep quality ! As far I understand, there should be lines/some sort of surface plane interpolating between the data! But nevertheless, I will attach a picture asap onto the question

Comment: Okay, I think I'm beginning to understand!

Comment: @MassDefect - I have now updated the question - hopefully the hand drawn picture and associated explanation will clear things even further!!

Answer (score 3):

I'll start by making a random dataset. Here we take 2 random numbers for the first two variables then set the third such that $a+b+c=1$ to be consistent with a Ternary plot. Here $a,b,c$ correspond to carbs, fat, protein respectively. We take the 4th variable to be another independent random number which corresponds to sleep for your case. Lastly we select only the data where $\{a,b,c\}>0$

```
data = Select[Table[
{a, b, 1 - a - b, RandomReal[]} /. {a -> RandomReal[], b -> RandomReal[]}, {i, 5000}],
 # == Abs[#] &];
```

We'll want to define our transformation from 3 variables down into our triangular 2D grid and convert our data over. This I just pull directly from Wikipedia.

```
toGrid[p_] := 1/2 {2 p[[2]] + p[[3]], Sqrt[3] p[[3]]};
dataPts = {10 toGrid[Most@#], Last@#} & /@ data;
```

Next we'll define some quantities to draw our triangular grid with

```
pts3D = Select[Tuples[Range[0, 10], {3}], #[[1]] + #[[2]] + #[[3]] == 10 &];
pts = toGrid /@ pts3D;
ptsG = Table[toGrid /@ Select[pts3D, #[[i]] == 0 &], {i, 3}];
lines = {Thread[{ptsG[[1]], ptsG[[2]]}], 
   Thread[{ptsG[[2]], ptsG[[3]]}], 
   Thread[{ptsG[[1]], Reverse[ptsG[[3]]]}]};
```

Add some styling and text to spruce it up

```
st[sz_] := Style[#, Black, Bold, FontFamily -> "Times", sz] &;
rot = 60 Degree;
ticks = st[12] /@ Table[10 i, {i, 0, 10}];
labels = {Rotate[Text[st[16]["Carbs"], {1.5, 5}], rot],
   Text[st[16]["Fats"], {5, -1}],
   Rotate[Text[st[16]["Protein"], {8.5, 5}], -rot]};
mkTicks[ind_, ang_, off_] := Table[
Rotate[Text[If[ind == 2, Reverse[ticks], ticks][[i]], 
    ptsG[[ind, i]] + off], ang], {i, Length[ticks]}]
```

Finally draw it! Here sleep is a number between 0 and 1 with 0 being red, 1/2 being blue, 1 being green and anything in between a proportional blend between the 3.

```
Graphics[{Point /@ pts, labels, Line /@ lines, mkTicks[1, rot, {1/4, 1/4}],
 mkTicks[2, 0, {-2/5, 0}], mkTicks[3, -rot, {1/5,-1/3}], Opacity[0.25],
 {FaceForm@Blend[{Red, Blue,Green}, #[[-1]]], Disk[#[[1]], 0.2]} & /@ dataPts}]
```

Obviously a non-random dataset should show some more revealing patterns. In my experience 3D graphs are really hard to make look nice and convey the data in a digestible way, I think this way should work nicely.

[image: Graph]

### edit:

Here's some quick and dirty code for an idea of a `DensityPlot`. Because my data is random it looks mostly like a solid block of color. You can clean it up and add all the axes and stuff if you like.

```
int = Interpolation[dataPts, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
dataInt[x_, y_] = If[y < Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] Sin[rot] && y < Sqrt[(1 - x)^2 + y^2] Sin[rot],int[x, y], I];
plt2 = DensityPlot[dataInt[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

[image: DenGraph]

Comment: Many thanks for this - it does seem to be similar to what I had in mind. Just to clarify, would I be able to do this on https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/trial/? Secondly, if I now wanted to use my own data, rather than a random data set, how could I input this data set ? Finally, I appreciate that a 3D graph will be messy!, If however, I want to show continuous change, as in a 2D line graph, interpolating the data points, then I might need to have a 3D graph - would it be possible to get some advice on this as well to see how complicated and convoluted it may seem! Many thanks.

Comment: You can copy and paste the code into wolfram.com/mathematica/trial to see if it works. Import your own data with an `Import` statement (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html). You can interpolate easily with `Interpolation` (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html). You can do this and use a `DensityPlot` to still use a 2D color graph or I suppose a 3D one. I actually did this with the sample data above but was unimpressed by the result. Perhaps if your data is well structured it'd come out nice. See edit for details.

Comment: many thanks - I tried to do the import but it didn't work - is there a way I can manually enter my data ? When I googled this, It said to use control comma to do a new column but this didn't work on my Mac - have I got this correct?

Comment: What kind of file is your data stored in? If you can host it online and share it with me I can show you how to import it.

Comment: Right now it is on excel but I could try some other method too - how do I share it with you?

Comment: I could try google sheets which has sharing capabilities?

Comment: That works, or just host the XLS/XLSX on google drive and share the link

Comment: Hi @bRost03 - Here is the link for the data -https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NIHp18mNrLTKXL3XNw8OzhJQrJulm7GI/view?usp=sharing.                                                                                                                    in my actual experiment I have 15 people, but I thought that may get a bit cluttered, so I have reduced the data to 5 people - I hope this helps you to explain my problems!

Comment: Zoom out and you should be able to see the whole data set, ask me if you have any questions or I haven't been clear!

Comment: just wanted to make sure that you got the data in the end!

Comment: I got your email but will not have time to get back to you until Monday

Comment: No worries! Thanks for the favour again