# How to round tick line ends in the plots

Tags: plotting, graphics, customization

I would like to have rounded ticks in my Mathematica plots. They look much better for thick frames

```
Plot[ {Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 3 Pi}, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick]]
```

gives 
[image: plot with square tick ends]

but I would like to round them, to get something like

[image: plot with round tick ends]

There is a function `CapForm["Round"]` but it is not clear how to use it with plots.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23910/diagonal-tick-marks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is another approach which is based on converting the plot to PDF format first. It makes the tick marks accessible as regular `Graphics` objects. Specifically, they (and the frame) show up as open `JoinedCurve` that can be identified by pattern matching. That leads to the following:

```
p = Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 3 Pi}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick]];

First@ImportString[ExportString[p, "PDF"], "PDF"] /. 
 JoinedCurve[{{{0, 2, 0}}}, x_, 
   CurveClosed -> {0}] :> {CapForm["Round"], 
   JoinedCurve[{{{0, 2, 0}}}, x, CurveClosed -> {0}]}
```

[image: plot]

What I did here is to replace the identified curves by wrapping them in `{CapForm["Round"], ...}`. This will affect all straight lines, including the frame itself (but the frame doesn't have end points because the corners overlap anyway). The plot lines themselves are *not* affected by the rounding because they aren't straight lines.

The advantage of this approach is that you don't have to manually calculate and specify the tick positions: the ticks will be modified in post-processing without changing their positions. The disadvantage is that the ticks in the resulting plot can no longer be modified by changing the options with `Show`, because they are "baked in".

Comment: Just wonderful. I'll spend the next hours playing with your answer :)

Comment: (+1) Nice! There is built-in [`FullGraphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullGraphics.html) function designed exactly for the purpose you achieve (in a hackish way) with `Import[Export[...]]` but unfortunately its support seems to be dropped since at least version 5. `Export` to PDF rounds all the coordinates to 16-bit precision and the `Import`ed plot will have lesser accurate positioning of the graphical primitives than the original plot (though it is still sufficient for the most purposes).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Yes, that's right. But `FullGraphics` was never reliable. And when you're talking about plots with ticks etc., I think we can assume that a reduction to 16-bit precision will be visually imperceptible. This precision issue is indeed important when your goal is to use the vector graphics in some other high-res operation later. Then I don't think one would want a frame and ticks in the first place, though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you will have to build your own graphic primitives. Something like this:

```
Show[
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 5}],
 Graphics[{GrayLevel[0.3], Table[Disk[{n, 0}, {0.025, 0.04}, {0, Pi}], {n, 0, 5}]}],
 ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]