# Disconnected Frame/Axes in Plots

Tags: plotting, graphics, output-formatting

Is it possible to have "Tufte" style figure axes? That is so that the axes do not need to connect or span the entire data range?

For an example of what I mean from the R's default histogram style:

[image]

I know how to get the ticks out etc ... but not how to break the axes at the origin or only draw the axes/frame for a subset of the graphic range.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can generate the axes separately using an "empty" `Plot`.

As you said you know how to specify the ticks, so I'll not bother to do it, but just show a simple example about what I mean:

```
hsgm = Histogram[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 1000]]

axes = Plot[I, {x, 0, 1}, (* the range of x is not important *)
    AxesOrigin -> {-4, -10},
    PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {0, 200}}
    ] // FullGraphics;
```

Then combine them:

```
Show[{hsgm /. (Axes -> _) :> (Axes -> False), axes}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: disconnected axes graphics]

**Note:** `FullGraphics` is well-known to be a *buggy* function, but if you find it usable, I'll glad to mention my [more detailed and interesting post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19963/17) on it.

## Update

To add labels like `FrameLabel`, we can't use `Frame` or we'll break the "disconnected" appearence. Thus we have to add them manually.

Here we use [the `completePlotRange` function invented by @AlexeyPopkov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18040/17) to detect the plot range of the histogram, and automatically generate the final plot.

```
Clear[myHistogram]
Options[myHistogram] = {"axesLabels" -> {}};
myHistogram[data_, OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{axesLabels, axesOriginFunc, hsgm, range, axes, labels, aspr = 1/GoldenRatio},
        axesLabels = OptionValue["axesLabels"];
        axesOriginFunc[{min_, max_}, p_: 0.1] := min - p (max - min);
        hsgm = Histogram[data, Axes -> False, PlotRangePadding -> None];
        range = Through[{Min, Max}@FindDivisions[#, 10]] & /@ completePlotRange[hsgm];
        axes = Plot[I, {x, 0, 1},
                    AxesOrigin -> MapThread[axesOriginFunc, {range, {0.1 aspr, 0.1}}],
                    PlotRange -> range
                   ] /. {HoldPattern[Frame -> _] -> Frame -> False} //
               FullGraphics// (*disable Antialiasing to make the axes and ticks un-blur*)
               # /. Line[pts__] :> Style[Line[pts], Antialiasing -> False] &;
        If[axesLabels =!= {},

           labels = Graphics[{
                              Text[axesLabels[[1]],
                                   {Mean[range[[1]]], axesOriginFunc[range[[2]]]},
                                   {0, 5}],
                              Text[axesLabels[[2]],
                                   {axesOriginFunc[range[[1]], 0.1 aspr], Mean[range[[2]]]},
                                   {0, -5}, {0, 1}]
                             }];
           Show[{hsgm, axes, labels}, AspectRatio -> aspr, PlotRange -> All],

           Show[{hsgm, axes}, AspectRatio -> aspr, PlotRange -> All]
         ]
  ]
```

**Usage:**

```
myHistogram[
            RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 1000],
            "axesLabels" -> (Style[#, Bold, 14, Darker[Red]] & /@ {"x", "Frequency"})
           ]
```

[image: disconnected frame example 2]

Comment: So great! Thank you

Comment: @Gabriel Glad I can help!

Comment: @Silva I am working through the details of this answer and I wonder if you could give an example that uses Frame instead of Axes ... as labeling the axes puts the label in the "wrong" place (at the end, not under). I worry that the `AxesOrigin` is key to getting the broken effect I want ... but then I don't know how to label the axes!

Comment: also does your other post cover all/most of the ways in which FullGraphics is buggy, or are there more?

Comment: @Gabriel Yes the `AxesOrigin` is the key, so there is no way to realize this by `Frame`. I think you'll have to place the labels manually, say by `Text[ ]`. I'll update the answer after breackfast. About the `FullGraphics`, I suggest you search it over this site to have a more general sight.

Comment: @Gabriel Please see my update.

Comment: thank you for all the help this is perfect!

Comment: Yes- for what it is worth, `FullGraphics` is being a PITA in version 10.0.1 again. the above generates a bunch of `Axes::axes: {{False,False},{False,False}} is not a valid axis specification. >>`

Comment: @flip Oh my... I'll try to fix it when having time... Thanks for telling me.

Comment: To fix in the above example, add a  ```/. {HoldPattern[Frame -> _] -> Frame -> False}```  after the `Plot`. It cleans up what comes out to make `FullGraphics` happy again.

Comment: @flip Thanks a lot! I have edited to include your fixing. Just for curiosity, how did you find the cure?

Comment: @Silvia Your update (+1) motivated me to write an answer with alternative solution which you can find useful.

Comment: @Silvia - I noticed that, for whatever `FullGraphics` might be doing, `Frame` was causing it trouble (I just kept deleting things until `FullGraphics` didn't bomb).

Comment: @flip Thanks for the information! I loved `FullGraphics`, it's a pity it doesn't work well now...

Answer (score 2):

Based on the findings from [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83638/280) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83810/280) answers, I can suggest the following approach.

Let us make a histogram:

```
SeedRandom[10];
hist = Histogram[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 1000]]
```

> [image: histogram]

It has `AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio` (the default):

```
Options[hist, AspectRatio]
```

> ```
> {AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio}
> ```

Now we can place this histogram as `Inset` inside of another `Graphics` keeping both coordinate systems exactly aligned with each other. According to the [linked answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83638/280) we must specify explicit values for `ImageSize`, `ImagePadding`, `AspectRatio` and `PlotRange` (and set `PlotRangePadding -> 0` for simplicity).

Suppose we want the horizontal `ImageSize` of the histogram to be

```
width = 350.;
```

A suitable value of `ImagePadding` can be taken as `ImagePadding -> {{20, 5}, {15, 5}}`. Then with the default `AspectRatio` the vertical `ImageSize` can be calculated as follows (this mathematics not only undocumented: it directly contradicts the Documentation - but it is how this actually works):

```
height = (width - (20 + 5))/GoldenRatio + (15 + 5)
```

> ```
> 220.861
> ```

So the explicit `ImageSize` is `ImageSize -> {width, height}`. Of course it is a shame that *Mathematica* still can't calculate the `height` unassisted, and we must do this massage in order to get options like `ImagePadding` working properly!

The explicit value of `PlotRange` we may set as `PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {0, 250}}`.

Now everything is ready:

```
g1 = Graphics[{Inset[
    Show[hist, ImageSize -> {width, height}, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {0, 250}},
      FrameStyle -> Bold, ImagePadding -> iIP, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
     Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic], {0, 0}, {0, 0}, Automatic]}, 
  Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {0, 250}}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1], 
  FrameStyle -> Red, ImagePadding -> iIP/.8, GridLines -> Automatic, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed], ImageSize -> {width, height}/.8]
```

> [image: plot]

As one can see, the coordinate systems of the inset and the enclosing graphics are exactly aligned to each other. Now we may remove the `Frame` and `GridLines` from the inset:

```
g1 = Graphics[{Inset[
    Show[hist, ImageSize -> {width, height}, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {0, 250}},
      ImagePadding -> {{20, 5}, {15, 5}}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
     Frame -> False, Axes -> False], {0, 0}, {0, 0}, Automatic]}, 
  Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {0, 250}}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1], 
  FrameStyle -> Red, ImagePadding -> {{20, 5}, {15, 5}}/.8, 
  GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed], 
  ImageSize -> {width, height}/.8]
```

> [image: plot]

Let us add another `Inset` containing only `Frame` with intrinsic coordinate system exactly aligned to the coordinate system of the enclosing graphics:

```
stretching = (3 + 3)/(5 + 5);
additionalPadding = (1 - stretching)*(350 - (20 + 5));
Show[g1, Graphics[
  Inset[Graphics[{}, ImageSize -> {width, height}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {0, 250}}, FrameStyle -> Blue, 
    ImagePadding -> {{20, 5 + additionalPadding}, {15, 5}}, 
    PlotRangePadding -> 0, Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, 
    AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio/stretching], {0, 0}, {0, 0}, Automatic]]]
```

> [image: plot]

Now we can keep only the bottom frame and move it a little lower putting `Offset` as the second argument of `Inset`:

```
g2 = Show[g1, 
  Graphics[Inset[
    Graphics[{}, ImageSize -> {width, height}, 
     PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {0, 250}}, FrameStyle -> Blue, 
     ImagePadding -> {{20, 5 + additionalPadding}, {15, 5}}, 
     PlotRangePadding -> 0, Frame -> {{False, False}, {True, False}}, 
     AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio/stretching], 
    Offset[{0, -10}, {0, 0}], {0, 0}, Automatic]]]
```

> [image: plot]

In the same way we can add left frame:

```
stretching = (200 + 0)/(250 + 0);
additionalPadding = (1 - stretching)*(350 - (20 + 5))/GoldenRatio;

g3 = Show[g2, 
  Graphics[Inset[
    Graphics[{}, ImageSize -> {width, height}, 
     PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {0, 200}}, FrameStyle -> Brown, 
     ImagePadding -> {{20, 5}, {15, 5 + additionalPadding}}, 
     PlotRangePadding -> 0, Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, 
     AspectRatio -> stretching/GoldenRatio], {0, 0}, {0, 0}, Automatic]]]
```

> [image: plot]

Removing unnecessary elements and adding `Offset`:

```
g3 = Show[g2, 
  Graphics[Inset[
    Graphics[{}, ImageSize -> {width, height}, 
     PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {0, 200}}, FrameStyle -> Brown, 
     ImagePadding -> {{20, 5}, {15, 5 + additionalPadding}}, 
     PlotRangePadding -> 0, Frame -> {{True, False}, {False, False}}, 
     AspectRatio -> stretching/GoldenRatio], Offset[{25, 0}, {0, 0}], {0, 0}, 
    Automatic]], GridLines -> None, Frame -> None]
```

> [image: plot]

Voilà!

Comment: Very interesting approach and linked posts! I cant help thinking if only we have a handy function to generate arbitrary axis (including curved ones).

Comment: Not to mention the easy ability to invert, say, the y-axis like we do in neuroscience all the time... Grr.